# USO DEL WHILE DO EN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, while

Como debo usar el WHILE DO en MySQL

me sale error en SET I=(I+1); // esto lo uso para la sumatoria y avance del WHILE

```
WHILE I<CotId AND Aux=0 do
SET Nom_CatPer = (SELECT Nombre_CatPer FROM  tbl_categoria_permisos WHERE Id_CategoriaPermisos = I);
SET Sig_CatPermisos = (SELECT Siglas_CatPermisos FROM  tbl_categoria_permisos WHERE Id_CategoriaPermisos = I);

If Nom_CatPer = _Nombre_CatPer then
    SELECT ("#101") INTO _Sw;  -- #101 ERROR NOMBRE DE CATEGORIA PERMISO REPETIDA
    SET Aux=1;
ELSE
    If Sig_CatPermisos = _Siglas_CatPermisos then
        SELECT ("#102") INTO _Sw; -- #102 ERROR SIGLAS DE CATEGORIA PERMISO REPETIDA
        SET Aux=1;
    END IF
END IF
SET I=(I+1); -- aqui me señala error en SINTAXIS
END WHILE
```

Comment: Para futuras preguntas, por favor procura añadir las etiquetas relevantes (en este caso, era importante añadir [mysql].

Comment: muchas gracias estimado

Comment: Las variables de usuario no llevan @ adelante?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta así:

```
SET @I = 0;
    SET @Aux = TUVALOR;
    WHILE @I < CotId AND @Aux = 0 do
        SET @Nom_CatPer = (SELECT Nombre_CatPer FROM  tbl_categoria_permisos WHERE Id_CategoriaPermisos = @I);
        SET @Sig_CatPermisos = (SELECT Siglas_CatPermisos FROM  tbl_categoria_permisos WHERE Id_CategoriaPermisos = @I);

        If @Nom_CatPer = _@Nombre_CatPer then
            SELECT ("#101") INTO _Sw;  -- #101 ERROR NOMBRE DE CATEGORIA PERMISO REPETIDA
            SET @Aux=1;
        ELSE IF @Sig_CatPermisos = @_Siglas_CatPermisos then
            SELECT ("#102") INTO _Sw; -- #102 ERROR SIGLAS DE CATEGORIA PERMISO REPETIDA
            SET @Aux=1;
        END IF
    END IF
    SET @I=(@I+1);
END WHILE;
```

Las variables en MySQL inician con un `@`, el END WHILE al final utiliza `;`. Intenta con eso.

Comment: ya hice eso me sale error, en otras variable como lo hice no me sale error solo me sale ese I=I+1;

le puse el (;) al finalde del WHILE DO (END WHIL;) me sigue saliendo error

Comment: Si en ves de utilizar SELECT ("#101") INTO _Sw, usas simplements SELECT "#101" ?

Comment: Con este codigo SELECT ("#101") INTO _Sw estoy asignando #101 a mi variable _Sw, este esto imcompleto SELECT "#101"

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS ESTIMADO